# Are translating questions on topic?

Tags: support, broken-code

I'm attempting to translate the Matlab code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981679/1391441) to Python. I'm halfway done, but I've never really written Matlab code and I'm having trouble finishing the final function.

Can I ask for help here regarding this not-complete code or would this be considered off-topic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about code translation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/questions-about-code-translation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *all* the code has to work as intended. If a part of it doesn't work, then it's off-topic.

Related Questions

- [Questions about code translation](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189)
- [Project translation from Java to C#](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6849)
- [Code typed in from a non-text source or converted from another language and isn't working - is this in the scope here?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8532)
- [Can you post code that works on one version of a interpreter (ex:Python 2) but not on another (ex:Python 3)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8916)